# How to store email template in PHP?

Tags: php, sendmail

I have the following code to send users a verification email, which contains some variables such as username and token for verification purpose. The variable obviously changes on an individual basis. However, I would like to store this message separately in the PHP include_path so that I can re-use it somewhere else if need be. I don't want to hardcode it like it is now:

```
$to = $username;
$subject = 'Account Verification';
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
$message = "
Date sent:$now

Thanks for signing up! 

Your account has been created, however we need to verify that this is your email address. Here is your verification token which you should copy and paste on the verification page:

<strong>$token</strong>

Alternatively, click the below link to activate your account:

http://localhost/login/verification.php?username=$username&token=$token 

If you did not register with us. You <a href='http://localhost/login/'>can click</a> here to report this to us, or ignore this email.

Thanks,

The LocalHost Team
";
mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

So three questions:

1. How do I store this message to be like a template in such a way the variables are still accessible?
2. How do I turn this message into a nicely HTML formatted message with html markups?
3. Can I do this:

   $to = $username;
   $subject = 'Account Verification';
   $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
   $message = include "verification_template.php";
   mail($to, $subject, $message);

Comment: No, you can't. include() doesn't return the code. What you want is some variant of `eval()`, which is generally a bad idea. Don't do HTML mails with php's mail() function. in fact, don't use PHP's mail() at all. it's hideously stupid. Use PHPmailer or Swiftmailer (google them) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the inclusion like this:

```
ob_start();
include $filename;
$message = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: And in your mail-headers include a line like   `Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1` if you're sending HTML-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to php, you can use template engines like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) to generate the html/text needed for your emails.

The advantage of using a templating engine is that your template can contain simple logic (such as conditionals, loops for handling dynamic data.

Comment: Trying to learn how to use Smarty now. I'm pretty confused about SMARTY_DIR constant. I don't understand it's purpose? It looks like it's just another constant, because you need to define it, then use it to look for the library. But if you use absolute path, or a path relative to your include_path to find the library, this saves you an extra line you require to define the SMARTY_DIR to begin with?... confused... Can you please explain its use? Thanks